# Splitting a large directory in parts

Tags: batch-file

Anyone knows how i could sort out data in directories by size to lets say 8GB then whatever overflows create a new folder with the same name as the original directoryName_1 ,directoryName_2 and so on using batch script
Basically I have a bunch of eml's stored in directory tree like this

```
E:\EMAIL\EML
├───SA36-7
│   ├───0
│   │   ├───0
│   │   ├───1
│   │   ├───2
│   │   ├───3
│   │   ├───4
│   │   ├───5
│   │   ├───6
│   │   ├───7
│   │   ├───8
│   │   ├───9
│   │   ├───a
│   │   ├───b
│   │   ├───c
│   │   ├───d
│   │   ├───e
│   │   └───f
│   ├───1
│   │   ├───0
│   │   ├───1
│   │   ├───2
SA44-3
├───0
│   ├───0
│   ├───1
│   ├───2
│   ├───3
│   ├───4
│   ├───5
so on
```

I need to make sure that each of these top mail directories SA44-3 is not larger then 8GB, so the script should calculate the size of each top level folder and if its over 8GB create a new one Called eg. SA44-3-1
sa44-3-2 and so on and move the remainder of the data to the new folder

this is how far i got

```
@echo off
setlocal

set maxbytesize=800000

set n=1

set nf=0

FOR /R %%f IN (*.eml) DO (
    IF !n!==1 (
      SET /A nf+=1
      ("%CD%")-!nf!
    )
MOVE /Y "%%f" ("%CD%")-!nf!

IF !n!==!maxbytesize! (
      SET n=1
    ) ELSE (
      SET /A n+=1
    )
)
```

So the end result should have the directories that look something like this

```
E:\EMAIL\EML
├───SA36-7
├───SA36-7-1
├───SA36-7-2
├───SA36-7-3
├───SA44-3
├───SA44-3-1
├───SA44-3-2
```

Each one of these directories should be anything between 10KB to 8GB but not larger then that. teh sub-directories \0 \1 \2 are not important as long as the mail 'SA' directory stays as a root folder name

Comment: Batch math tops out at 2 GB.  You can use VBS or Powershell or another tool.

Comment: Even 2GB would be fine tho as long as its possible using batch

Comment: You would need to edit your question and clarify how the data will be split - by folder, or by file, maximum subdirectory sizes, and give examples of what the resulting folder structure will look like.  FWIW If you said 8 GB then how does 2 GB suddenly fit the bill?

Comment: Hi foxidrive, so i mentioned, I need to split the data from the top level folders - so the above directory tree can look like this E:\Email|\SA44-3 - and all the data can be in it - this folder however should not be larger then 8GB - so if it is 2GB that's still ok

Comment: There's not enough information to write a script.

Answer (score 1):

The disk space for files is assigned in *clusters* that usually are 4 KB size, that is, a file with 1 to 4096 bytes takes up one cluster, 4097 to 8192 bytes takes up two clusters, etc. This way, it is more precise to manage clusters instead of bytes in file sizes and this method allows to manage the requested 8 GB limit in the 32-bits integer number used by SET /A command.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /A "KB=1024, MB=1024*KB, GB=1024*MB, ClusterSize=4*KB, MaxClusters=GB/ClusterSize*8"

rem The current ClusterSize may be obtained this way:
rem for /F "tokens=4" %%a in ('fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo E: ^| findstr /C:"Bytes per cluster:"') do set ClusterSize=%%a

cd /D E:\EMAIL\EML
for /F %%d in ('dir /B /AD') do (
   set "dirToMove="
   set /A nextDir=0, clusters=0
   for /R "%%d" %%f in (*.eml) do (
      set clusters+=(%%~Zf-1)/ClusterSize+1
      if !clusters! gtr !MaxClusters! (
         set /A nextDir+=1, clusters=(%%~Zf-1)/ClusterSize+1
         set "dirToMove=%%d-!nextDir!"
         md "!dirToMove!"
      )
      if defined dirToMove move "%%f" "!dirToMove!"
   )
)
```

PS - I suggest you to change the title; this topic is not about "Sorting files by size", but "Splitting a large directory in parts".

Comment: Nice.  And here I had just been polishing a subroutine to add big numbers, treating each number as an array with a `for /L` loop iterating over each digit.  Your solution makes more sense and uses about 30 fewer lines of code.  +1